# How to validate form fields before moving to next slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm building a form that is broken up into slides. I want to make it so that when a user clicks the arrow to move to the next slide, the form first validates whether the information he/she put in is valid for the input field. If so, it moves on and if not it alerts the use with some visual effect.

Here is the code

```
    $('.next').click(function() {
    if(indexBG === 3){
        indexBG = 3;
        $('#RF'+indexBG).css('display', 'block');
        $('#RF'+indexBG).fadeOut(500);
        $('#RF'+indexBG).fadeIn(500);
     }
     else {
           validateIt();
     }
     function validateIt() {
           if(!isValidEmailAddress($('#email-reg-input').val())) {
                $('#email-reg-input').css("border","red solid thin");
            }   
            else {
                  $('#RG1').css('background-color','green');
                  $('#RG1').html('33% Complete!');
            }
            if($('#name-reg-input').val() == ''){
                  $('#name-reg-input').css("border","red solid thin");
             }
             else {
                  $('#name-reg-input').css("border","green solid thin");  
             }
     };
     });
```

Comment: And what is the problem/question?

Comment: `if(indexBG === 3){ indexBG = 3;` – and this is from the better-safe-than-sorry school of coding …?

Answer (score 0):

Form validation can get pretty tricky. Especially when you consider all of the different use cases and variations of junk users can enter. So, since you're already using jQuery, you might want to check out the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).